# How to Varnish over https with Apache?

Tags: ssl, https, varnish, apache2

I read few times that nginx is possibly faster and there are other SSL terminators

[Varnish and HTTPS with Apache without Ngnix, Pound, HAProxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/871749/varnish-and-https-with-apache-without-ngnix-pound-haproxy) (can't comment yet)

**Anybody successfully setup varnish with Apache?**

I found another guide https://bash-prompt.net/guides/apache-varnish/

but unfortunately even though I setup varnish:80 Apache:443 with Proxy to Apache:8080 it's only working for http where curl shows

> Via: 1.1 varnish-v4

but https not:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 15:21:10 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 103
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Connection: close
```

Comment: I also see no activity in the varnishlog with **curl -v https**

Answer (score 1):

Although the guide of your choice has a picture showing that https go through varnish (as well as http), the rest of that section contains nothing that would indicate so. The `ProxyPass` puts traffic right to  Apache localhost:8080 that serves DocumentRoot bypassing Varnish.

You need to `ProxyPass` to the IP:port that your varnish listens on.

Comment: Thanks Kuba for looking at this, I thought it would go through varnish due to the default config of `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` with `backend default {.host = "127.0.0.1";.port = "8080";}`

Comment: I changed **ProxyPass** to :80 and indeed it's appearing in **varnishlog** but I see no speed improvement and doubt the caching is working. I noticed each time i reload a test.php it's also appearing in the **appache access.log** each time, which doesn't occur going through http where the page only get's served by varnish.

Comment: @Markus Well that's a different question, but I think it's too broad to be valid on this site.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options
https://bash-prompt.net/guides/apache-varnish/
or
use nignx as a proxy to handle https requests
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/09/https-everywhere-with-nginx-varnish-apache/